# How to space string character at a particular position in python

Tags: python-3.x, string

Hi Guys is there a way to properly space a statement/ strings in a particular position. i was able to successfully scrape some text for constant monitoring of daily Covid-19 results, but the output isnt well spaced as i want. example of my output below

> 2,016,549Total confirmed cases18,112Today
>   127,635Total deaths1,056Today
>   492,338Confirmed recoveries24,373Today
>   1,396,576Active confirmed cases51,522 (4%)Critical
>   21%Mortality / closed cases6%Mortality / confirmed cases
>   16,096,027Total tests337,502Today.

i would rather the out put be atleast more readable like this

> 2,015,031 Total confirmed cases 16,594 Today
>   127,541 Total deaths 962 Today
>   490,534 Confirmed recoveries 22,569 Today
>   1,396,956 Active confirmed cases 51,570 (4%)Critical
>   21% Mortality / closed cases 6% Mortality / confirmed cases
>   16,061,619 Total tests 303,094 Today

i have tried everything i can read up using join(), split() and i still didn't get the needed result.i had to manually space the better result in a text file. if i have to always manually space it, then the whole purpose is lost

Comment: Can you share how you gathered the original data and an executable version of your source code? Then we might be able to tell you how to join the text with correct spacing.

Comment: The alternative option is to use a regex rule to add spaces/new lines between numerical values and word characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `re.sub` here:

```
inp = "2,016,549Total confirmed cases18,112Today 127,635Total deaths1,056Today 492,338Confirmed recoveries24,373Today 1,396,576Active confirmed cases51,522 (4%)Critical 21%Mortality / closed cases6%Mortality / confirmed cases 16,096,027Total tests337,502Today."
output = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-z])(\d)', ' \\1', inp, flags=re.I)
output = re.sub(r'(\d)(?=[a-z])', '\\1 ', output, flags=re.I)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
2,016,549 Total confirmed cases 18,112 Today 127,635 Total deaths 1,056 Today 492,338 Confirmed recoveries 24,373 Today 1,396,576 Active confirmed cases 51,522 (4%)Critical 21%Mortality / closed cases 6%Mortality / confirmed cases 16,096,027 Total tests 337,502 Today.
```

The regex replacement logic here is to match and capture a single digit, which is either preceded or proceeded by an adjacent letter.  If there be a match, then we replace with that same digit, along with an extra space for padding.

Comment: I would also add `output = re.sub(r'(%|\))(?=[a-z])', '\\1 ', output, flags=re.I)` and `output = re.sub(r'(?=[\s])(\()', '\\1 ', output, flags=re.I)` to handle brackets and % signs

Comment: @GTBebbo Good observation, but keep in mind if we get too carried away the logic could also end up making replacements we don't want.